# How did the orange highlight for selecting dissapear?

Tags: android

So for some reason that standard orange highlight that happens when you click on something in an Android app has completely vanished. I never put any code anywhere to change its color(to my knowledge). Does anyone know of  reasons this would happen? Or how to manually add it back via code(XML or Java).

Comment: Is this in reference to a button click?  If you add your own background image to a button you'll no longer get the orange highlight on click.  You'll have to add that manually, and if that's the case I'll link you to a reference.

Comment: Yeah, its for a list item click. I manually set a background color on it, not an image though. What would the reference be?